# Laravel Eloquent giving different result from MySQL / MariaDB query when using "WHERE CONCAT"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a laravel eloquent query that is giving me a different result from the same query that I try at MariaDB

Eloquent:

```
$invoice = PurchaseInvoice::select("purchase_invoices.*", "purchase_contracts.contract_no", "partners.name as partner_name")
                    ->join("purchase_contracts","purchase_contracts.id","purchase_invoices.purchase_contract_id")
                    ->join("partners","partners.id","purchase_contracts.partner_id")
                    ->join("commodity_po","purchase_contracts.id","commodity_po.purchase_contract_id")
                    ->where("purchase_invoices.invoice_no", 'LIKE', '%'.$request->q.'%')
                    ->orWhere("purchase_invoices.po_additional_no", 'LIKE', '%'.$request->q.'%')
                    ->orWhere("purchase_contracts.contract_no", 'LIKE', '%'.$request->q.'%')
                    ->orWhereRaw("(CONCAT(`contract_no`, `po_additional_no`) LIKE '%?%')", [$request->q])->get()
```

and it will generate query like this :

```
select `purchase_invoices`.*, `purchase_contracts`.`contract_no`, `partners`.`name` as `partner_name` from `purchase_invoices` inner join `purchase_contracts` on `purchase_contracts`.`id` = `purchase_invoices`.`purchase_contract_id` inner join `partners` on `partners`.`id` = `purchase_contracts`.`partner_id` inner join `commodity_po` on `purchase_contracts`.`id` = `commodity_po`.`purchase_contract_id` where (purchase_invoices.invoice_no LIKE '%SLP0622/6A-%' or purchase_invoices.po_additional_no LIKE '%SLP0622/6A-%' or purchase_contracts.contract_no LIKE '%SLP0622/6A-%' or (CONCAT(`contract_no`, `po_additional_no`) LIKE '%SLP0622/6A-%')) and `purchase_invoices`.`deleted_at` is null;
```

when I run the query on laravel, it give me empty result

[image: image for eloquent]

but when I run the generated query on MySQL it give me 1 result

[image: image for mysql]

Does anyone know why this can happened? is this because there is a slash '/' on the query?

Comment: In orWhereRaw you are matching with exact value instead of contain. May be due to this you are geting null.   * ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT(`contract_no`, `po_additional_no`)", 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')->get()*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'%?%'` is not a valid parameter. You need to pass it like:

```php
->orWhereRaw("(CONCAT(`contract_no`, `po_additional_no`) LIKE ?)", [ '%'.$request->q.'%'])->get()
```

Comment: whoa its working, thank you very much! I feel so stupid LOL